# What bug is this? And how can I get rid of them?

Tags: pest-control, pest

I recently became an expat to a southeast Asian country and found that bugs are a fact of life here, this one particular breed has really brought out the heeby-jeebies in me. This little critter tends to come out around midnight, and they are crazy fast. They go from the floor to across my laptop keyboard (while I'm typing) in about 10 seconds. They tend to come in the directions of my wooden cabinets, and are always running at top speed. I find the infestation strange because we're on the 9th floor of a building, keep the flat pretty clean, and there's no obvious food source for them. I catch about a dozen of these a night just from within view, heaven knows how many more are lurking around the dark corners. One note - they look like lone rangers to me. I haven't seen a group of them scattering about when I open a cabinet or anything.

It appears to be somewhat seasonal - they became an issue as the temperature worked its way above 39c/95f.

My wife (who is local) says they aren't cockroaches, and when I looked online at local cockroach species, there are none that look the same. I also don't think it's a termite since it doesn't have claw-like head. **Can anybody help me figure out what kind of bug this is and how to eradicate it from my home?** Photo below:

[image: In Bag]
[image: With Ruler]

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: Perhaps ask on the Biology Stack

Comment: An item in your photo to indicate scale would be helpful. That's not a cockroach. It's a fairly common little beetle. I think we have the same here in Minnesota.

Comment: @isherwood I just added with a ruler in CM (thanks for suggestion). It's about 1cm long.

I added to DIY in hopes of getting advice on how to get rid of them before we have to get the entire flat sprayed but can add to biology SE too.

Comment: I'd look into whatever borer beetles are common in your area.

Comment: I agree, it looks like a borer beetle, which means the "food" it is living on could be the cabinets themselves, not anything in them!